# Link column in a IG with DA to update a table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How to create a link column in Interactive Grid to execute dynamic action ?

I created a demo app to delete employee from emp table where I have a DA with 4 steps:

1.Confirmation

2.JavaScript Code

```
var empNo = $(this.triggeringElement).attr('href');
apex.item('P1_EMPNO').setValue(empNo);
```

3. PL/SQL Code

   begin
   delete from emp
   where empno = :P1_EMPNO;
   end;
4. Refresh region

It doesn't work at all, when I click on the link column it does nothing

I created a demo app, I would appreciate any advice:

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1

workspace: igtest

user: demouser

pass: apexdemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. This was on my environment, not yours. It is an editable IG report on the emp table, page 55. The functionality is that when a link is clicked the salary is increased by 1.

Short explanation of this technique:

- Set the data attribute of link to "EMPNO" so it can be read by javascript
- Use a class to capture the click event
- Trigger an event when link is clicked
- Listen for that event and execute the pl/sql code.

**1.**
Add a link column to the report. I used the "Create Column" option of the report to add a column of source type "SQL Expression" with sql expression:
`'<span class="fa fa-check-circle-o raise_salary" aria-hidden="true" data-empno="'||EMPNO||'"></span>'`

**2.**
Add dynamic action "Raise Salary Clicked", Event scope "dynamic"
[image]

Add a true action of type Set Value:

[image]

Add a true action of type Execute Javascript Code:

Action: Execute Javascript Code

Code: `$.event.trigger("raisesalary");`

**3.**
Add a dynamic action "After raisesalary event", Event scope "dynamic"

[image]

Add a true action of type "Execute Server-side Code":

PL/SQL Code: `UPDATE emp SET sal  = sal + 1 WHERE empno = :P55_EMPNO`

Items to submit: P55_EMPNO

Add a true action of type "Refresh" to refresh the interactive grid region.

Comment: Koen, thank you for the solution. I created page 55 in my application (credentials in my post above). It works only once, to update salary column multiple times I have to refresh a page, is there any way to avoid refresh of the page?

Comment: In step 2 it states "Event Scope: dynamic" - did you do that ? When it is static or once the dynamic action will no longer work after a dom change. Event scope is a setting in the dynamic action itself, not in the individual actions.

Comment: I didn't. I changed to dynamic and now it's working perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help. Please mark the question as answered :) No better way to say thank you in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

`this.triggeringElement` is not working as expected in Oracle Apex after the version 21 as far as I know.
I checked your demo application and saw you are trying to execute Dynamic Action by a Jquery selector. I advise you to use column selector as: [image]

EDIT: When I deeply checked your demo app, I saw that you are using the `EMPNO` column of type link and setting the link with `#EMPNO#`.
This means this link is trying to go to the URL: [image] apex.oracle.com/pls/apex//#EMPNO# which is not valid. Either change link URL to a valid modal confirmation dialog page you would create, or remove the link so that dynamic action would be triggered.