# Oracle APEX - how to read a cell from interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex

The same question once again but with (I hope) better explanation:

I created the most simple case:

1. An Interactive Grid IG with data source EMP ( table with 14 records contains Ename, Job, HireDate, Salary etc. etc.)
2. Text field P7_ENAME

After running it looks like below:

[image]

What I would like to do is to copy Ename from selected record of IG to P7_ENAME field .
I found several tutorials (text and video) how to do it. Most of them suggest to create dynamic action SelectionChange on IG and when TRUE add a JavaScript code something like below:

```
var v_ename;
model = this.data.model;
v_ename = model.getValue( this.data.selectedRecords[0], "Ename");
apex.item( "P7_ENAME" ).setValue (v_ename);
```

and the second step is to create another action: Refresh.
So finally I have a dynamic action with two steps :  the first one is a Java script code and the second refresh function on my P7_ENAME field.

Sounds simple and it is simple to repeat/implement.  A guy (I suppose) from India published a video on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuFz885Yndw)  which I followed and in his case it works good. In my case it simple does not work - field P7ENAME is always empty, no errors appears.  Any idea why ?  Any hints, suggestion ?

thanks for any help

K.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767311/link-column-in-a-ig-with-da-to-update-a-table/ It is quite similar I think

Comment: Koen - your hints are always helpful but this time I wanted to avoid using link. An idea of using console suggested by cengiz was good enough .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to debug and achieve what you are trying to do is as follows:

1. create the Dynamic action with the following setup:

   ````
   -when -> selection change[interactive grid],
   -selection type -> region, region -> your IG region, 
   -client side condition -> javascript expression: ```this.data.selectedRecords[0] != undefined```
   ````
2. First action of the true of the DA with the type: execute javascript code and fire on initialization is turned on, code: `console.log(this.data.selectedRecords);`
3. Run your page, and check the browser console. You should see an array of columns when you select a record from that IG as follows:[image]

Find in that array, which sort number of the array contains the data that you want to use for the page item. Let's say I want the 3rd element which is "2694" then I should change my dynamic action's execute javascript code to:

```
    var value = this.data.selectedRecords[0][2];
    apex.item( "P7_ENAME" ).setValue (value);
```

The last thing I should do is add another true action (and the refresh action at the end) to the same dynamic action with type 'SET VALUE' and 'PLSQL EXPRESSION' as type, put :P7_ENAME in the expression, items to submit P7_ENAME and affected element: item / P7_ENAME as follows: [image]

Comment: Your hint was priceless.  It took me a long while to get familiar with Browser's console . But finally it works .   Now I sent to console every variable I add to my code to debug it during execution  :)

Comment: This is a great answer. Anyone knows why I'm getting 'undefined' when running this piece? console.log(this.data.selectedRecords);