# Getting updating value from IG

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2, interactive-grid

I need to store the updated value from the IG in the P12_EMPNO page element.

[image]

To do this, use this code in DA --- > Run Javascript code

```
var changedValue = apex.item("N001").getValue();
apex.item("P12_EMPNO").setValue(changedValue);
```

But the value is not stored in the P12_EMPNO page item.

Note: I only need to save the value I'm updating...

For example: If the value 1003 (already present) is updated to 1004 (update value), I need to store 1004 in P12_EMPNO.

See page 12

Environment:https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/

Workspace: shajin_wk

username: Test

pwd: Test@123

Comment: There are a lot of blogs on how to get cell values from an interactive grid. The code you posted *apex.item("N001").getValue()* is NOT valid interactive grid javascript. The interactive grid component has its own javascript api. Check for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72816629/oracle-apex-how-to-read-a-cell-from-interactive-grid) but do search and read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can able to store the data. But Now I got one problem, when I change the value and press enter throwing the error (insufficient privileges) But the value are stored correctly and I can able to update the collection .

2. In IG 1st row (Qty column) I can edit and able to stored the value to the page item but not able to update the collection.

However I can able to stored the value and update the collection for the remaining rows but giving error (insufficient privileges).

Comment: I have added credentials to the question. Can u see page 12 on that

Comment: There is no username in those credentials. Pls provide workspace and username and pwd.

Comment: Here is an exact answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72816629/oracle-apex-how-to-read-a-cell-from-interactive-grid

Comment: added credentials to the question. Can u see page 12 on that

Comment: Please provide *exact* details on how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: On page 12 click Add to add product to the collection(IG). After that edit value on Qty column and hit enter.

Comment: 2. After we add 2 or more products to the IG, we can able to edit the QTY column of the previous rows (not the last added rows) but the values are not updated and not error.

Comment: I'm not getting an error and I don't see immediately why it doesn't work. I did add "P12_SELECTED_ROW_VALUES" in items to submit. I'd suggest using apex_debug in your server side dynamic action. 
However, I would not update the collection with a dynamic action on change of the IG, but use page processing - that is the way an interactive grid is supposed to be used.  [Here](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2019/07/23/customizing-dml-in-an-apex-interactive-grid/) is an example

Comment: Actually if we add more product and edit the last row Qty it is throwing the error and updated the value on IG(collection). but if we edit last previous row it will not throw any error nor update the value. If u want u can create a copy of the 12 .

Comment: Here I don't want to add data directly to the table. For that I have used collection and once all data is finalized will add it to the table.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I suggest updating the collection using page processing, not DA. I'm sorry but I don't have time to debug your application. I suggest debugging and taking a different approach (page processing not DA).

Comment: Ok Thanks! Koen. will try page processing. one last thing the "insufficient priviledge" error is raised while executing the javascript code(code1). Can you help me how to stop display/ popup that error on the screen.

Comment: I see one error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." but I have no idea where that comes from

Comment: Can u please see page 13. I have removed all the codes and added only one Javascript in Dynamic action. and added a page process. When user edits the value and hit Enter, using Dynamic action I have invoked SAVE functionality and on the process am updating the collection. But the problem is when user hit enter all thing works fine  but values are not updating to the collection but showing SUCESS message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your application, the reason you're getting the error is because of the following attributes in the page process:

- For the page process, the editable region needs to be set to the interactive grid region.

[image]

- In the page process, use the *column names*, not the column headings:

```
DECLARE
  l_emp_collection VARCHAR2(100) := 'PRODUCT_LIST';

begin
    case
        :apex$row_status
        when 'U' then
            apex_debug.info(
                p_message => 'KL Debug: SEQ_ID: %0, N001: %1, N002: %2, C001: %3, QTY: %4',
                p0 => :SEQ,
                p1 => :N001,
                p2 => :N002,
                p3 => :C001,
                p4 => :N003);

            APEX_COLLECTION.UPDATE_MEMBER ( p_collection_name => l_emp_collection,
                                              p_seq => :SEQ,
                                              p_n001 => :N001,
                                              p_n002 => :N002,
                                              p_c001 => :C001,
                                              p_n003 => :N003 );

    end case;

end;
```

Note that you can use apex_debug to log entries that can be viewed in debug mode.